# How to remove spaces in PowerShell append

Tags: powershell, ftp

Hi i am trying to upload my files to FTP account but facing a problem i want to append all files paths to **ftpupload.txt** here is my `ftpupload.txt` contents:

```
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
O : \ p i c s 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 3 3 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 1 2 2 9 . j p g 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 4 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 2 0 1 5 . j p g 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 3 4 . j p g 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 1 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 4 9 . j p g 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 4 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 9 2 4 . j p g 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 4 1 . j p g 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 1 2 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 5 6 . j p g 
 
 O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 2 1 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1.jpg
```

[image: Screenshot After appending text]

Powershell **command** to list paths:

```
gci o: -r | % {$_.FullName} >>C:\Users\vb3\desktop\ftp\ftpupload.txt
```

***i want text file output something like this*** how can i fix this issue i am new to powershell so tell me simple way to fix this issue

```
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
send O:\151104051533IMG_20151103_111229.jpg
send O:\151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
send O:\151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
send O:\151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
```

Comment: See [PowerShell Out-File outputs extra spaces in between characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64412442/850848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often an encoding issue.

So, know that in PowerShellv7, all cmdlets, as well as the redirection operator, use UTF8 text.

However, not all things in Windows PowerShell will, but there is -Encoding. You can set UTF8 (or another encoding) as a default, by putting this:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('*:Encoding', 'UTF8')
```

... in your user-profiles and all your distributed/production scripts.

You can also, just remove the spaces directly. Walk thru to get to a final solution.

```
# Use your output directly or assign it to a variable use the below
(@'
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
O : \ p i c s 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 3 3 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 1 2 2 9 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 4 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 2 0 1 5 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 3 4 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 1 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 4 9 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 4 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 9 2 4 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 4 1 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 1 2 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 5 6 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 2 1 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1.jpg
'@).Split("`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -replace '\s{2}' | 
ForEach {
    If ($PSItem -match 'O :')
    {$PSItem -replace '\s+'} 
    Else {$PSItem}
}
# Results
<#
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
O:\pics
O:\151104051533IMG_20151103_111229.jpg
O:\151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
O:\151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
O:\151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
O:\151104051640IMG_20151103_123924.jpg
O:\151104051658IMG_20151103_130741.jpg
O:\151104051712IMG_20151103_130756.jpg
O:\151104051721IMG_20151103_1.jpg
#>


# Pseudo file create... and modify
@'
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
O : \ p i c s 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 3 3 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 1 2 2 9 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 4 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 2 0 1 5 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 3 4 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 1 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 4 9 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 4 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 9 2 4 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 4 1 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 1 2 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 5 6 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 2 1 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1.jpg
'@ | 
Out-File -LiteralPath 'D:\Temp\ftpUpload.txt'

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\ftpUpload.txt'
# Results
<#
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
O : \ p i c s 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 3 3 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 1 2 2 9 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 4 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 1 2 0 1 5 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 5 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 3 4 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 1 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 2 4 9 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 4 0 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 2 3 9 2 4 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 6 5 8 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 4 1 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 1 2 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1 3 0 7 5 6 . j p g 

    O : \ 1 5 1 1 0 4 0 5 1 7 2 1 I M G _ 2 0 1 5 1 1 0 3 _ 1.jpg
#>

# Read the file back
ForEach ($Line in (
                (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\ftpUpload.txt').Split("`r`n",
                [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -replace '\s{2}')
            )
{If ($LIne -match 'O :')
{$Line -replace '\s+'} 
Else {$Line}}
# Results
<#
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
O:\pics
O:\151104051533IMG_20151103_111229.jpg
O:\151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
O:\151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
O:\151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
O:\151104051640IMG_20151103_123924.jpg
O:\151104051658IMG_20151103_130741.jpg
O:\151104051712IMG_20151103_130756.jpg
O:\151104051721IMG_20151103_1.jpg
#>

# Modify the raw file
$CleanedContent = ForEach (
                            $Line in (
                                (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\ftpUpload.txt').Split(
                                    "`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::
                                    RemoveEmptyEntries
                                ) -replace '\s{2}'
                            )
                           )
                    {
                        If ($LIne -match 'O :')
                        {$Line -replace '\s+'} 
                        Else {$Line}
                    }
Set-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\ftpUpload.txt' -Value $CleanedContent

# Read the file back
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\ftpUpload.txt'
# Results
<#
ftpusername
ftpPassword
cd htdocs
quote pasv
binary
O:\pics
O:\151104051533IMG_20151103_111229.jpg
O:\151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
O:\151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
O:\151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
O:\151104051640IMG_20151103_123924.jpg
O:\151104051658IMG_20151103_130741.jpg
O:\151104051712IMG_20151103_130756.jpg
O:\151104051721IMG_20151103_1.jpg
#>
```